# React Native Windows error C1083: The include file cannot be opened: 'winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.h'

Tags: react-native, react-native-windows

I am experiencing this error when trying to run a Windows desktop app created with React Native and React Native Windows. I have tried different ways to start the project and different versions of both React Native and Visual Studio and Windows SDK, yet I always get the same error. Any solutions?

*"dependencies": {
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.3",
"react-native-windows": "0.72.5"
}*

*Windows Kits: 10.0.19041.0*

*Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.5*